# Does flutter support animated svg?

Tags: animation, svg, flutter

Im trying to create a preloader for my app. But I want it to be high quality. Not GIF. So animated SVG is what I want to use. Is there a way to put animated SVG in flutter?

Comment: Btw, what sort of animated SVG are you talking about? SMIL or CSS-based?

Answer (score 4):

Use **Flare-Flutter** new vector animation tool https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flare_flutter

Comment: this.  with a note that you need to also signup at 2dimensions.com

Answer (score 2):

Flutter currently doesn't provide any SVG support directly.

You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_svg for basic SVG support

and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lottie_flutter or https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluttie for animated vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to put animated SVG in flutter?

There isn't. **Flutter doesn't not support SVG**.
There is a [third party library](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg) for basic support but no animation/SMIL support.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but I see its not answered correcly so far.

https://pub.dev/packages/drawing_animation I guess, this is what you want. It Draws the svg with animation.

Comment: This package doesn't work with the latest Flutter 2 version. I have opened the issue. Let's hope if author updates it. @MohammedYakub M.

Answer (score 0):

[Rive](https://pub.dev/packages/rive) is a way to go.
"Rive is a real-time interactive design and animation tool"